# Set a certain row and column and multiply certain cell number. Multiply float by certain cells in excel and python in a data frame

Tags: python

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F2w7.png)

This is a replica excel pivot table I created. The table looks at Amazon, Walmart and more brands percentage of delivery time, revenue per month and more. The key elements is the column Operator with Giant and Safeway. I only want to change only those in the data frame where they line up with Total mbps Required. I tried using the code below. I want only the total mbps required to change for Giant and Safeway for the formula I have.

```
H=400
G=600
F= G*df['Total Mbps Required']/H

df.loc[df['Operator'] == 'Giant','Safeway', G*df['Total Mbps Required']/H]
```

This is the error I get.

```
"None of [Float64Index([1834.4006682989377, 179.66005151022537, 155.54786620504268,\n              1001.5192845836114, 28.272425249169434],\n             dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
lst = ['Giant','Safeway']
def new_values(x):
    G = 600
    H = 400      
    if x in lst:
        return (G*x)/H
    else:
        return x
    
df['Total mbps required'] = df['Total mbps required'].apply(lambda x:(G*x)/H)
```

Comment: I tried this code but I got G= 600
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block error

Comment: Check your indentation, lines should be properly spaced and indented

Comment: Okay this was the next error I got. SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.

Comment: This is again an indentation fault (Check the if-else statements and make sure they're properly indented). If you could add the image i'll be able to help